# How to use deltas on 3 sentences in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, delta

Suppose I have the following sentences:

```
s1 = "The red dog jumped over the hill, followed by the crazy clown."
s2 = "The green fox jumped over the hill, followed by the crazy clown."
s3 = "The red dog jumped over the hill, followed by the dumb dolphin."
```

I want to be able to store the deltas of s2-s1 and s3-s1 in some compressed form, like: s2_d_s1 = -"red dog" +"green fox"

Then I can take those deltas and apply them in arbitrary order, either s2_d_s1 first or s3_d_s1 first. So that the following are equal:

```
apply_delta(apply_delta(s1, s2_d_s1), s3_d_s1) ==
    apply_delta(apply_delta(s1, s3_d_s1), s2_d_s1)

apply_delta(s1, s2_d_s1) == "The green fox jumped over the hill, followed by the crazy clown."
```

How would I do this in Ruby? Is there a library that would do it?

(The actual content is going to be more complex than sentences. It's documents.)

I've tried fossilize but can't figure out how to handle changing sentence size (applying the first delta changes the sentence size, which screws up applying the second delta):

```
s1 = "The red dog jumped over the hill, followed by the crazy clown."
s2 = "The green fox jumped over the hill, followed by the crazy clown."
s3 = "The red dog jumped over the hill, followed by the dumb dolphin."
s2_d_s1 = Fossilize.create(s1, s2)
s3_d_s1 = Fossilize.create(s1, s3)
Fossilize.apply(Fossilize.apply(s1, s2_d_s1), s3_d_s1)
DeltaApplicationError: Output was -1, but I expected 63!
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/fossilize-1.1.1/lib/fossilize.rb:107:in `apply'
    from (irb):14
    from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Would [ruby-git](https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git) help you?

Comment: Git keeps track of the entire state of files, not just deltas, so not really what I'm looking for? It's a common misperception that git keeps diffs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a gem for your needs, it's called Differ.

```
require 'differ'

@original = "Epic lolcat fail!"
@current  = "Epic wolfman fail!"  

@diff = Differ.diff_by_line(@current, @original)
  # => "{"Epic lolcat fail!" >> "Epic wolfman fail!"}"

@diff = Differ.diff_by_word(@current, @original)
  # => "Epic {"lolcat" >> "wolfman"} fail!"
```

Comment: That just does diffs. I want to apply deltas.  BTW, I also tried fossilize which uses the FOSSIL SCM delta compression algorithm but I can't figure out how to apply multiple deltas if they change the size of the sentence.